# MILP Penalty Function Only for Negative Values

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, linearization

This is (hopefully) an easy answer but I haven't dealt with this before.

I have a MILP which includes an unbounded, continuous decision variable.  However, I generally don't want this decision variable to take negative values, so I want to include a penalty in the objective function where there is zero penalty incurred for a positive value, but for negative values, the penalty is proportional to the absolute value.  Basically, I want a value of -100 to be penalized twice as much as -50, and 10x as much as -10.

Right now I have formulated an indicator variable that is 1 if the decision variable is negative, which incurs a penalty; but this penalty is the same for any negative value.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $x$ denotes your free variable, you can penalize the term $f(x)=\max\{-x,0\}$ in your objective function, which you can linearize by replacing it with a variable $y$, and constraints $y\ge -x, y\ge 0$.

Comment: Another good approach. +1

Comment: I like this a lot.  I'll then just put -y in the objective function (since it's a maximization).  Thanks

Answer (score 12):

You do not need to introduce an indicator variable.  Suppose $x$ is your free variable.  Introduce nonnegative variables $x^+$ and $x^-$, replace $x$ with $x^+-x^-$ throughout, and penalize $x^-$ linearly in the objective.